# How can I enable wireless access for a guest user?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

Using Windows 7 Ultimate, I want my relatives & friends to log into my system as a guest and be able to use the internet. I don't know how to enable the wireless network option for guests. Do I need to edit the registry or something?

I searched only to read that "Its not possible". I don't wanna believe that! If that's true, what is the work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be useful to you:
[How to Enable User-Specific Wireless Networks in Windows 7](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43782/how-to-enable-user-specific-wireless-networks-in-windows-7/)

Comment: Can you please summarize the most important steps from that link? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enable internet for guest account by creating a guest account, then in your own computer account (personal, non guest account) try these steps:

- `control panel->network` and `internet->network` and `sharing center->`  click on `Change Advanced Sharing settings` (far left hand side)
- Ensure you click on *Network Discovery* `ON`.
- log on/log off and then back into your guest account. You should be able to click internet and it will come on.

It will not show access and it will say denied but you can use the internet by wifi connection if you enable network discovery! I have a guest account with windows 7 and I turn the net on/off by doing this often; depending on when you want someone to use the net. I disable all picture/file sharing for my own purposes however, as some prefer privacy in this regard.

Hope this helped! :) Again you won't see the net icon but it should work!